# Calculating Amplitudes with FeynArts

Tags: feyncalc

I'm following a lecture on how to use FeynCalc, FeynArts, I have done exactly what they say to me to do. Everything was going ok until that point. FeynArts is not calculating amplitudes, error message says I did not pass a FeynAmpList object, but neither the guy on the lecture and it seems to work for him.
If anyone could give me some clue about what is happening here I would appreciate very much. Thanks in advance.

I'm using Mathematica 12, FeynCalc 9.0, FormCalc 9.6 and FeynArts 3.1.

*** edit: the lectures can be found in this git-hub repository:
    https://github.com/misho104/FeynLecture

[image: Error message]

Comment: You seem to confuse FeynCalc and FormCalc, which are two very different codes. Judging from your screenshot, you are trying to use FormCalc and FeynArts, so FeynCalc is not really relevant here. Is that so? Furthermore, providing a link to the lecture you are following would make it easier for people to help.

Comment: @vsht the lectures are posted as notebooks here in this git-hub respository: https://github.com/misho104/FeynLecture

Comment: So, the problem is, I have reinstalled Mathematica. I tried to ./compile in  FormCalc 9.9 directory as they say I have to, but an error message pops-up: "No 'math' command found"
I think the previous installation I did not paid attetion to that error message!

Comment: If it is a problem with the installation of FormCalc it might be better to contact the developer.